# Get as much as possible from Application bundle (.app)

Tags: ios, macos, reverse-engineering, disassembly, .app

I want to know as much as possible technical information about given Application bundle .app, e.g:

- compiler used
- frameworks used
- implementation details

QuickLook plugin that show extensive information about .app would be ideal, but I don't know about such.

Answer (score 2):

## GUI

- [MacDependency](https://code.google.com/p/macdependency/) shows all dependent libraries and frameworks of a given executable, dynamic library or framework on Mac OS X. It is a GUI replacement for the [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) command, and provides almost the same functionality as the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) on Windows.

## Command line

- [nm](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) displays the name list (symbol table) of each object file in the argument list.
- [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) displays specified parts of object files or libraries.
- [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) examining the Objective-C runtime information stored in Mach-O files. It generates declarations for the classes, categories and protocols.
- [class_dump_z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z)

### list all linked symbols

```
nm -u /Applications/.app/Contents/MacOS/executable | sort | less
```

### Display global (external) symbol names (no value or type).

```
nm -g -j executable | sort | uniq | less
```

### list all libraries the app has linked to.

```
otool -L executable
```

### Display the contents of the __OBJC segment used by the Objective-C run-time system.

```
otool -ov executable | less
```

### disassembly

```
otool -tvV executable | less
```

### show implementation addresses

```
class-dump -A executable | less
```